# Cannot download the whole source code for a web page

Tags: html, r, selenium, url, rcurl

I am trying to get a list of hyperlinks in the following webpage

http://www.oabmg.org.br/examedeordem/home/index

When I inspect the source code in Chrome I can find those links, which are pdf files (I just do a `CTRL+F pdf` and I find them), for example: http://www.oabmg.org.br/areas/examedeordem/doc//2017.2%20(XXII%20EOU).pdf

However, anyway I try to get the source code in R, to get all the pdf link addresses, I never get the whole source code.

I have tried `rvest`, `RCurl` (switching peer verification on) and `selenium` and none of them get the whole code.

Every time I get the html code (using `read_html`, `getURL`, or `getPageSource()`) and try to find any instance of a string 'pdf' I get nothing.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(getURL('http://www.oabmg.org.br/examedeordem/home/index'), 'pdf'))

character(0)
```

Anyone knows what I can do to get the whole code?

Comment: The table with the pdfs is being generated with javascript. If you inspect the page you can find the script `exame.js` which shows it is submitting a POST request (with the value of the dropdown) to `/exameDeOrdem/Home/getDocExame` which returns the links you want.

Comment: Yeah, im pretty horrible with js coding and the likes. Could you point to me how to get those links, imagining i am an 8 year old kid?